# (Doom) Emacs Org Latex Preview Toggle Errors On New Fragments But not Existing Ones

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I am running Doom Emacs, just upgraded, with org mode and I have two latex fragments.

```
Where n is the row position and m is the column position
\end{text}

\begin{text}
Where n is the row position and m is the column position.
\end{text}
```

The top fragment was written/modified in this file, where I removed the period from the end, while the bottom fragment was copied from a different file that compiled without errors in the past.
Trying to use c-c c-x c-l to preview the bottom fragment works fine, but the top fragment gives the error

```
org-compile-file: File "/tmp/orgtexI8CLoH.dvi" wasn’t producedPlease adjust ‘dvisvgm’ part of ‘org-preview-latex-process-alist’.
```

If I were to modify the bottom fragment in any way shape or form, or type out a new fragment, it would produce the same error, leading me to believe the problem only happens on new fragments, not existing ones. In addition, if I was to add the period back to the top fragment, it compiles without errors. This behavior also persists across files, only latex fragments I have written and compiled in the past work, others error. I have everything installed in the correct place, as the org latex preview command does work some of the time.
In addition, if change the preview renderer back to default by commenting out

```
(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'dvisvgm)
```

in my config.el file, or if I change dvisvgm to another program like imagemagick or dvipng, no fragments work.

Conclusion:
At some point in the past, something changed and broke new latex fragments, but somehow existing ones were stored and still compile successfully.